# updating weblogic server offline: seeking guidance

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

i need assistance with updating weblogic server offline. Due to security constraints, my server doesn't have internet access. Can anyone provide a step-by-step guide or script to update weblogic server offline? I appreciate any help in advance. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.